# Converting Access Code to SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following code in Access and I need it to work in sql, the Is numeric portion is throwing me off.

```
Sum([Employee Count]*IIf(IsNumeric([Length]),[Length],0)) AS Total_hours,
```

Comment: For which DBMS do you want this? SQL is just a *language* it is *not* a DBMS product.

Comment: I can never tell why people throw negatives on posts... I guess you didn't show what you've tried already.  No?  Bunch of nazis here.  If you're downvoting.. might be helpful if you explained yourself a little.  In the name of progress.

Answer (score 2):

You will replace the `IIF()` with a `CASE` expression. The [`IsNumeric()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) is valid in SQL Server:

```
Sum([Employee Count]*
    case when IsNumeric([Length]) = 1
          then [Length]
          else 0 end) AS Total_hours,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just filter "not isnumeric" out since 0 will not impact SUM aggregation.

```
select
Sum([Employee Count]*[Length]) AS Total_hours
...
where isnumeric([Length]) = 1
```

See code below.

```
declare @table table (abc varchar(100))
insert into @table
select '1'
union select '200'
union select '200A'

select sum(convert(int,abc))
from @table
where isnumeric(abc) = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bbebc/2/0)