# Combining CASE STATEMENTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, case

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converting Access Code to SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446507/converting-access-code-to-sql)

I have an access code using `IIF` statements that have 2 in 1 and I am trying to rewrite them for SQL as `CASE` statements but I am hitting some speedbumps.

```
Sum(IIf([RRDD] Not Like "12*" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "13*" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "16*" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "17*" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "2706" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "2707" 
    And [RRDD] Not Like "2331",
    CDbl([2011 Total])*IIf(IsNumeric([Dur_In_Hours]),
    CDbl([Dur_In_Hours]),0),0)) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

WHere the first `IIF` is being multiplied by the second IIF is where I am confused, and i need it to be in SQL format

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiplying `(CASE ... WHEN ... END)` by another `(CASE ... WHEN ... END)`, so what's the problem?

Comment: I dont know how to format the code in SQL version, IE the second CASE WHEN portion

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the logic in both SQL Server and Access.  Here is the SQL Server version:

```
Sum(case when left([RRDD], 2) not in ('12', '13', '16', '17') and
              RRDD not in ('2706', '2707', '2331') and
              isnumeric(dur_in_hours) = 1
         then [2011 Total] * cast(Dur_In_Hours as float)
         else 0.0
    end) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

In both systems, `like` is going to incur more overhead than a search through a list of constants.  The cast is safe because it is in a `where` clause (I'm also adding an answer to the reference above, since the answers are not correct).

The replacement for `iif` is generally `case`, although this function has been added into SQL Server 2012 (that said, I sort of hope no one uses it).

Answer (score 1):

```
Sum(case when [RRDD] Not Like '12%' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '13%' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '16%' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '17%' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '2706' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '2707' 
And [RRDD] Not Like '2331'
then cast([2011 Total] as float) * 
    case when ISNUMERIC([Dur_In_Hours]) = 1
        then cast([Dur_In_Hours] as float) 
        else 0 
    end
else 0 
end) AS SP_DOM_COST
```

While `IsNUmeric` is a valid TSQL function it is [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567804/sql-isnumeric-not-working) [not very](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400318/why-does-isnumeric-return-1/7400383#7400383) [nice to play with](http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/01/13/isnumeric-broken-only-up-to-a-point/). IF you get odd results check out some other [existing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517777/t-sql-determine-if-value-is-integer) answers for workaround. Depending on your data you may be fine though.

Comment: Not sure but perhaps `*`s should be changed to `%`s.